# Vaadin - Wrap arbitrary Component with HTML

Tags: vaadin

I wanted to wrap a Component in HTML, let's say an "a". Is there an easy way to do this? ps. I do not want to add a ClickListener.

Something like:

```
CssLayout layout = new CssLayout();
SomeHtmlElement html = new SomeHtmlElement("a");
html.addAttribute("href","http://stackoverflow.com");
html.addComponent(layout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a
[CustomLayout](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.6/com/vaadin/ui/CustomLayout.html) to
put components into arbitrary HTML surroundings [(See also the Book of
Vaadin)](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-customlayout.html)

Creating that HTML is not a direct part of Vaadin.  So you have to pick some
third party library for this.  For the sake of example is used
[Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), as this is included in the Vaadin server and it
allows for DOM manipulations (which I don't use):

```
// run with `spring run --watch <file>.groovy`
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1')

import com.vaadin.ui.*
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.*
import com.vaadin.shared.*

@com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI
@com.vaadin.annotations.Theme("valo")
class MyUI extends UI {
        protected void init(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest request) {
        // create some HTML and provide a "place-holder" via `data-location`
        def doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse('<main><h1>Hello World</h1><p><span data-location="button"/></p></main>')
        def button = new Button("Hello World", { Notification.show("Hello World") } as Button.ClickListener)
        // read the CustomLayout from an InputStream
        def c = new CustomLayout(new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.toString().getBytes('UTF-8')))
        // place the button in the CustomLayout via its name chosen by `data-location`
        c.addComponent(button, 'button')
        content=c
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking for. Please read the question again.

Comment: @steve Or you could describe to me, how a) CustomLayout is not solving the subject of your question or b) a HTML-Label + Jsoup is not solving the thing you describe in your code -- which are btw two different things.

Comment: CustomLayout is close to what I was looking for, but I was asking more for a "builder" that would accept a vaadin component and define the outer html element. Label option is a no go, as yes, you can add HTML within the label element, however, you cannot add a component to a label. I'll just create a new custom component utilizing CustomLayout with ByteArrayInputStream. ex.  new CustomLayout(new ByteArrayInputStream(doc.toString().getBytes());

Comment: @steve Thanks for clarifying.  I have adjusted the answer.